# How to write the algorithm of this matrix in this ascending order in C.Where is error in my code?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am writing this code to print the following matrix in this spiral order(spiral by column).But my code is printing totally different thing.

```
a     a+7  a+8   a+15
a+1   a+6  a+9   a+14
a+2   a+5  a+10  a+13
a+3   a+4  a+11  a+12
```

Here is what i did:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int Sum = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0,n;
    printf("Insert the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Insert the value of a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d  ",a);
            a = a + 7;
            printf("\t");
        }

        printf("%d",a);
        a = a + 1 ;

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't change `a` in the inner loop (i.e. don't do `a = a + 7;
`). Instead use a temp variable in the inner loop.

Comment: Are you intending `n` to be the total number of printed elements, or the size of the row/column?

Comment: @llap42  it is  value of row and column

Comment: One issue you will have is that although you ask the user for `n`, you have specifically coded for the case of `n=4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I approached this is to build the matrix of values you actually want, but doing so in *column* order, where we can relatively easily control the logic of value progression by row.  Then, with that matrix in hand, print out the values in *row* order, as you want the output:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 7;
    int n = 4;
    int array[4][4];

    for (int c=0; c < n; ++c)
    {
        for (int r=0; r < n; ++r)
        {
            // values ascending for even columns
            if (c % 2 == 0)
            {
                array[r][c] = a + c*n + r;
            }
            // values descending for odd columns
            else
            {
                array[r][c] = a + c*n + n-r-1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Probably the clearer approach to read. Although it's worth noting the giving up the row order traversal makes this less cache friendly for bigger arrays. Also, the `std::cout` isn't C, but here's an upvote anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, I think OP selected randomly... +1 by me

Comment: @Biegeleisen thank you for you answer it is working. When the first time you answered it did not worked. Now it is ok!

Comment: But in C programming you cannot declare int inside for loop. It gives you error!

Comment: @Armani I think it is compiler-specific.  In the demo I linked, which uses GCC, there is no problem with my code and it runs.  But point taken.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working. there was another true answer it also worked, i don't know if that guy deleted it or what!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this complex mechanism to keep track of all elements you can just calculate the value to add at any time by simple arithmetic.

See this

```
int row;
int column;
printf("\n");
for (row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < n; column++) {
        int base; 
        int flag; 
        if (column % 2 != 0) {
            base = (column+1)/2 * 2*n - 1;
            flag = -1;
        }else {
            base = column/2 * 2*n;
            flag = 1;
        }
        printf( "%d ", a + base + flag * row);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I hope you are able to follow this logic. If not feel free to ask.

Demo here:
[Ideone](https://ideone.com/OWf11N)

Comment: Declaring all the variables at the top, despite the limited scope of their use, is so 1989...

Comment: Can you update your solution so that the number `8` is not hard-coded, or at least is expressed as a multiple of some fixed parameter?

Comment: Oh my bad, will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @StoryTeller, everytime I write code like this, it hurts my brain. But it's less effort than having to figure out what standard the guy on the other side is using or having to change later. I have seen many students using even Turbo C.

Comment: They'll keep using it we don't nudge them towards better options :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using a matrix to calculate values before print them

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int i = 0, j = 0, n;
    printf("Insert the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Insert the value of a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    int matrix[n][n];

    for (i=0; i< n*n; i++)
    {
        // even columns ascending
        if (((i/n) % 2) == 0)
        {
            matrix[i%n][i/n] = a++;
        }
        // odd column descending
        else
        {
            matrix[n-(i%n)-1][i/n] = a++;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i< n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j< n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Insert the value of n: 4
Insert start value: 1
1   8   9   16  
2   7   10  15  
3   6   11  14  
4   5   12  13
```

Comment: Why the extra memory though? It can be done without it.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Why not? I prefer to use a matrix and an easier loop to print.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @LPs because you will run into all kinds of cache issues when either filling or dumping the matrix ( you cannot optimize both the accesses). Also memory accesses are costly for large n. I just mean when there is a cheaper solution, we should go for that.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Cheaper on what? I think it is clearer to fill matrix: you can debug it and see what is going on. For newbies should be clearer a matrix filling process with coordinated calculation then `base = (column+1)/2 * 2*n - 1;` and `a + base + flag * row` as per your answer. BTW personal opinions are OT.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two issues with your code as it is. As mentioned in the above comment, you are using the variable `a` in the loop calculation, so it is constantly being updated. This means your loop becomes invalid after a few iterations. If you define a dummy variable, this would avoid the problem. Secondly the implementation of the spiralling is close to being right, but it's not quite there.

Consider in the case `n = 4`. When you print along each row, the difference between a new element and the last alternates between values of `(2n - 1) = 7` and `1`. To take this into account, you could for example check every time you want to print whether the column index (`j`) is odd or even, and use this to determine which difference to add. Once you have the row machinery fixed, it shouldn't be difficult to extend it to the columns.